# Javascript updates entire column in boolean matrix

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update a specific index in a boolean matrix but it update the entire column. what might be the problem?

I'm attaching the code here:

```
const booleanMatrix = Array(5).fill(Array(5).fill(false));
console.log(booleanMatrix);

booleanMatrix[0][0] = true;
console.log(booleanMatrix);
```

first and second prints:

```
[
  [ false, false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false, false ]
]
[
  [ true, false, false, false, false ],
  [ true, false, false, false, false ],
  [ true, false, false, false, false ],
  [ true, false, false, false, false ],
  [ true, false, false, false, false ]
]
```

I expect it to be:

```
[
  [ true, false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false, false ]
]
```

Comment: Each row is referring to the same array. `Array(5).fill(false)` evaluates to a single object, which is copied by reference to fill each row in the initial matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
const inner = Array(5).fill(false);
const booleanMatrix = Array(5).fill(inner);
```

Of course when you update inner, it updates on each row, since each row is pointing to the same thing.

You need to do

```js
let x = Array(5).fill(null).map((i) => Array(5).fill(false));
console.log(x);
x[0][0] = true;
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const booleanMatrix = Array(5).fill(Array(5).fill(false));
```

This fills an array with 5 references to the same array.

```
Array(5).fill(false) // reference to one array
```

When you change one array, you're changing all of them, because they're all the same object in memory.

You need to create 5 different arrays and load each one of them:

```
let booleanMatrix = [
    Array(5).fill(false),
    Array(5).fill(false),
    Array(5).fill(false),
    Array(5).fill(false),
    Array(5).fill(false)
];
```

Alternatively:

```
let booleanMatrix = Array(5).fill("throwAway").map( () => Array(5).fill(false));
```

This will create 5 unique arrays